# Make a one column report list

Tags: shell-script, group

In the /etc/group we have many many users in one group, separated by comma like,
`jdoe,adoe,cdoes`, etc.
I need to make a (one column) list for my report that looks like:

```
jdoes
adoe
cdoe
.....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the group is named `groupname`...

Get the specific line out of the `group` file:

```
getent group groupname
```

Delete the bit of the result before the last `:`

```
getent group groupname | sed 's/.*://'
```

Replace the commas with newlines:

```
getent group groupname | sed 's/.*://' | tr ',' '\n'
```

Comment: Excellent answer, thanks, I appreciate it.